# Macports: assume yes on "Continue Y/N" prompts?

Tags: bash, macos, macports

I'm a complete noob when it comes to macports. I've just started a new job, they've given me a new work laptop and a basic bash script filled with just over 20,000 ports. I'm running macports 2.4.1 on OS X Sierra.

Occasionally a port wants my password, usually to allow a port to run on startup. So simply creating some sort of script to press y and enter over and over isn't going to work very well.

I've tried to search around but most people are looking for methods to stop macports installing dependencies altogether which is not what i'm after, I need it to simply assume that I do want to install all dependencies without asking for a prompt. I'm not sure if this is something I could do with an argument or by editing a config file somewhere.. or something that's possible at all.

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: "just over 20,000" - that's _all_ of macports (20,128)

Comment: And so it was.. bad instructions in the first place it turns out D:

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add the `-N` flag to the port command so "interactive questions are not asked."

From `man port`:

```
   -N
       Non-interactive mode, interactive questions are not asked
```

Comment: Note that this will *not* assume yes, but rather fall back to a safe default. Making the default yes would come with the risk of uninstalling things you might not want to uninstall. `-N` is also the default when standard output is not a terminal.

Comment: Thanks for the response both of you. This may well be a solution for me as I think this extensive list does include dependencies. oddly, I was already using the -q flag which according to the man should've set -N anyway. Carefully scouring the man page I can't really see how what I originally wanted is possible.. so i'll accept this for now. Still curious if anyone has a solution.

Comment: So I guess I misunderstood but -N still seems to be fetching most dependencies. Which is great.
`sudo port -N install portname`
For anyone who wants to know the usage

Answer (score 14):

If you really want to answer *yes*, non-interactive mode is not necessarily the right answer. As mentioned [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44794821/macports-assume-yes-on-continue-y-n-prompts#comment76603287_44808833) by @neverpanic, non-interactive mode merely falls back to a safe default rather than assuming *yes*, an affirmative response.

In order to really answer in the affirmative, you can always fall back to the good old `yes` command:

```
$ sudo -s                                                           
Password:
root@host $ yes | port install ImageMagick GraphicsMagick
```

Comment: For running as one-liner: `sudo bash -c "yes | port install ..."`.